# Does EditorHelper use ViewBag to pass data to corresponding template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, razor

I observed a somewhat peculiar behavior when overwriting the `Object.cshtm` template. The `Object.cshtm` iterates the `Model` properties and "sends" them to the appropriate template for rendering.

```
foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)        
{
    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, 
          "MyCustomTemplateCollection" + prop.TemplateHint) 
    //TemplateHint set by custom attributes
}
```

Everything works well: the template switches to the appropriate type template and inside those I can access `Metadata` properties:

```
string name = ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
string controllerName = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name;

//render property accordingly (using the property information)
```

However, if for some reason the `ViewBag` contains a (dynamic) property with the same name as one of the `Model` properties, the `ModelMetadata` is not completely generated; at least the `ModelMetadata` properties described above are set to `null`. For example, if in my controller I set `ViewBag.ProductName = myModel.ProductName;`, when the `ProductName` property gets in its corresponding template, the metadata does not contain the "expected" values.

The **solution** is quite simple: if, for whatever reason, the property needs to be saved in the `ViewBag`, it must be saved under a different name.

My question is: how does the `EditorHelper` pass the data to the templates? I wouldn't expect that `ViewData` and `ViewBag` "share" such information. Inspecting with *QuickWatch* I can see in the `Non-Public members`of the `ViewBag` a `ViewData` property which appears to be the same as the, lets say, generally available `ViewData` object. Why aren't the completely independent?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple answer to your question:

`ViewBag` is a dynamic wrapper for `ViewData`. They are effectively the *same thing*. Anything you put into `ViewData` is also in `ViewBag` and vice versa.

You can see the implementation of `DynamicViewDataDictionary` (which is what `ViewBag` is an instance of) [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DynamicViewDataDictionary.cs). As you can see, it simply holds an internal reference to the `ViewDataDictionary` that it wraps and delegates property access to dictionary elements.

So, when the framework passes `ViewData` into a template with a specific key and you assign a `ViewBag` property with a matching name, only one can win.

The other side of the coin - which I think is actually more relevant - is the fact that the static `ModelMetadata` methods responsible for providing metadata check `ViewData` *first* - before examining the metadata of the model object.

So, if you assign properties to `ViewBag` (and - by association - `ViewData`), these are the properties that will be matched to the expression you passed to the template and these won't have certain metadata such as that provided by data annotations on the model class.